# TCPDF Not supporting Chinese Character

Tags: php, tcpdf

Hi I am using TCPDF for generating PDF .. But Not able to print Chinese Characters ( CJK ).. Now I am getting only boxes after printing the pdf instead of characters.

Hear is my code I am doing like this

```
$pdf = new TCPDF("P", "pt", array(PdfPhotobook::pdfheight_land,(PdfPhotobook::pdfwidth_land)+(PdfPhotobook::pdfmargin*2)), true, 'UTF-8', false);
$fontname     =   $pdf->addTTFfont('../tcpdf/ttf/'.trim($json_obj->family).'.ttf');
$pdf->SetFont(trim($json_obj->family), '', ($font_size), '', false);
$pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);
$pdf->Output($savePath, 'F');
```

Please help me.

Comment: http://alucard-blog.blogspot.in/2013/06/tcpdf-how-to-display-chinese-character.html

Comment: @JayBhatt Thanks for the reference its working